# Microsoft Azure RDP Internet Connection

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp

So I accidentally "Disabled Internet Access" on my Windows RDP and now I can't connect there. My question is can someone help me out somehow turning internet access on again so I could connect to my VPS?

Thanks everyone who can help :)!

Answer (score 0):

If you've disabled internet access on your Windows RDP, you might need to access the server directly or through another means, like a console provided by your hosting provider. Once in, you can re-enable internet access through network settings. If you're unsure, contacting your hosting provider's support would be advisable for specific guidance tailored to your setup